# Bayes' Theorem with cases

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, bayes-theorem

Exactly $\frac{1}{5}$ people that live on earth have a condition
.There are two tests for this condition, the Z1 test and the Z2 test. When a person
goes to a doctor to test for this condition, with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ the doctor conducts Z1 on them and with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ the doctor conducts Z2 on them.
When Z1 is done, the outcome is as follows:

1. If the person has the condition, the result is positive with probability $\frac{3}{4}$.
2. If the person does not have the condition, the result is positive with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

When Z2 is done, the outcome is as follows:

1. If the person has the condition, the result is positive with probability 1.
2. If the person does not have the condition, the result is positive with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

A person is picked uniformly at random and sent to a doctor to test for this condition. The result comes out positive. What is the probability that the person has the condition?

Let A= Person has the condition and B= The test is positive. Now I have to calculate:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Now, in the above equation, $P(A)=\frac{1}{5}$,but how do I calculate $P(B|A)$ and $P(B)$ for both Z1 and Z2?

Comment: What about your previously solved problems, worked examples, and theorems?  What do these tools tell you?

Comment: I have made some more edits to my question.

Comment: For what it's worth, virtually no MathSE posted question that I have seen (from me or anyone else) that followed 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
has been downvoted. Instead, such questions are almost always upvoted, with 
MathSE reviewers going out of their way to try to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $A$ = diseased, $B$ = tests positive

$P(A|B) = \Large\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}
{P(B|A)\cdot P(A) + P(B|A^c)\cdot P(A^c)}$

**For Z1**

$P(A|B) =\Large\frac{\frac34\frac15}{\frac34\frac15 + \frac14\frac45}$

Compute similarly for $Z_2$, and then apply the law of total probability to combine the results. I suppose you can carry on by yourself now ?

Comment: Okay, so for Z1, I am getting $\frac{3}{7}$ and for Z2, I am getting $\frac{1}{3}$ and so my final result should be:
$\frac{3}{7} \times \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{25}{63}$ ,right?

Comment: @PsychBit: Haven't checked the arithmetic; the law of total probability has been done correctly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that at least this method is correct. The values should be correct, but I will still double-check once.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$

Comment: Also, is there a way to solve this by using Bayes' theorem just once to calculate for both Z1 and Z2?

Comment: @PsychBit: Z1 and Z2 are two fractions with different denominators, w1[a/(a+b)] + w2[c/(c+d)]. You should be able to understand why we compute them separately. Of course, we can combine the two parts by arduous algebra after  making the denominator common, but what would be the point ?

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense

Comment: @PsychBit:Whenever aanswer(s) serve your purpose, you should tick one  to dispose off the question